# Search and replace with attribute value in vim

Tags: vim

Trying to do a simple search and replace in Vim and failing miserably. My input is:

```
        <column name="ID" type="numeric(19,0)" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="TSTAMP" type="datetime"/>
        <column name="AMOUNT" type="numeric(19,2)"/>
        <column name="CURRENCY" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="GAINED_MONEY" type="boolean"/>
        <column name="ADJUSTMENT_REASON_ID" type="numeric(19,0)"/>
        <column name="ADJUSTMENT_TX_ID" type="numeric(19,0)"/>
```

I would like to replace each line with the contents of the name attribute, to get:

```
ID
TSTAMP
AMOUNT
CURRENCY
GAINED_MONEY
ADJUSTMENT_REASON_ID
ADJUSTMENT_TX_ID
```

My first attempt was:

```
:%s/.*name="\(\S+\)".*/\1/g
```

Then I thought maybe I should escape my escape sequence:

```
:%s/.*name="\(\\S+\)".*/\1/g
```

Then I thought perhaps I should add the verymagic switch, but have tried that and it doesn't seem to work either! What have I got wrong?

Comment: So reading here: http://vimregex.com/
one thing you need to do is swap `+` for `\+`, still doesn't work with just that though...

Comment: Mike, you are correct. The following works: :%s/.*name="\(\S\+\)".*/\1/g  If you would like to write that as an answer, I will tick it for you.

Comment: Sure, I put the answer I came up with as additonal explanation and because I didn't know the non-greedy-search quantifier `\{-}` in vim (in other regex's it's `+?` or `*?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure I'll put this for extra explanation, without using the `\v` very magic symbol we can see that `\{-}` is a non-greedy search (so as few characters as possible rather than as many as possible so this works:

```
:%s/.*name="\(.\{-}\)".*/\1/g
```

In addition if we were to have non-whitespace characters `\S` instead of wildcard `.` in the brackets we could put:

```
:%s/.*name="\(\S\+\)".*/\1/g
```

as pointed out by Hedley.

Comment: Did you test your second solution?  Try `\(\S\+\)` instead of `(\S\+)`.  I would use `[^"]*` instead of `\S\+`.

Comment: @benjifisher well caught, I didn't test it. fixed now, and good point, you could use the negative character set to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This substitution seems to work on your sample:

```
:%s/\v^.{-}"(.{-})".*/\1
```

Breakdown:

```
\v       --- 'very magic' because who likes backslashes?
^        --- anchor the pattern to the start of the line
.{-}"    --- match any character non-greedily until the next "
(.{-})"  --- match any character non-greedily until the next "
             and put it into capture group \1
.*       --- match the rest of the line
/\1      --- replace the whole line with capture group \1
```

Comment: I've accepted Mike's answer because my main problem was the missing backslash on the +, but this answer is very helpful too, so I've given you an upvote, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

And now for something completely different

```
:%norm di"Vp
```

- `:normal` runs normal commands on a range of lines
- `di"` will delete the first attributes contents
- `Vp` will replace the current line with the just deleted contents

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
:h v_p
```

Comment: This is very handy. I use text objects occasionally but I thought you had to be inside the object to get a match, so didn't realise you could do this. I don't use visual mode very often so didn't know about the Vp trick either, thanks!

Comment: nice, if I were to do this I'd have used a macro and applied it to all the lines, didn't know about %norm. thanks.